# How to retrieve a shard region form a different cluster node in akka?

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

In the below code, how cluster node FrontendNode can get reference to the shard region "SomeShardRegion" 
that is already started in the other cluster node BackendNode?
When I try the code below I get this exception: Shard type [SomeShardRegion] must be started first.

Note: I don't want to start another "SomeShardRegion" in FrontendNode!

```
object BackendNode extends App {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("ClusterSystem", config)

  ClusterSharding(system).start(
    typeName = "SomeShardRegion",
    entityProps = someProps,
    settings = ClusterShardingSettings(system),
    extractEntityId = idExtractor,
    extractShardId = shardResolver)
}

object FrontendNode extends App {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("ClusterSystem", config)

  // throws an exception:  Shard type [SomeShardRegion] must be started first
  val shardRegion = ClusterSharding(system).shardRegion("SomeShardRegion")
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you why you'd want to retrieve the region of another node? Maybe there is a better pattern for what u want to achieve

Comment: Sure. I'm doing DDD and initially would like my web frontend to talk directly to my aggregate root regions. Later I will introduce Saga (PM) for long running transactions which again needs to have references to aggregate regions to be able to coordinate transaction. In either case, I will run into the same problem shown above. Do you have an alternative suggestion? Please do let me know. Thanks.

Comment: What is DDD? My Cluster-sharding-fu is rusted, but I think you'd be better off with having the nodes that are part of the sharding have each a local actor that listens to a message channel (publisher streams or whatever they are called), and then your frontend can talk on the channel, and the listeners then propagate to their region coordinator. You'll have to handle multiple messages etc. tho.

Comment: It is Domain Driven Design. I understand what you mean. However, DDD introduces other patterns that akka has implemented without the need to have your actor subscribed to an event stream. I just figured out how to retrieve a shard region from frontend node. Will post the answer now

Answer (score 1):

Seems that I always have to start the region before I retrieve it. However, if I don't want entities to be created in the frontend I can 
[start shard region as a proxy](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/cluster-sharding.html#Proxy_Only_Mode)

Comment: Thanks for posting your own answer. This can be helpful to many :)

Answer (score 0):

I found that a lot of people reference the documentation without pointing exactly where, so here is the link to the documentation, the closest point to the [answer](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/cluster-sharding.html?language=scala#Proxy_Only_Mode) .

Quoting the documentation

> Messages to the entities are always sent via the local ShardRegion.
>   The ShardRegion actor reference for a named entity type is returned by
>   ClusterSharding.start and it can also be retrieved with
>   ClusterSharding.shardRegion. The ShardRegion will lookup the location
>   of the shard for the entity if it does not already know its location.

Here a bit of code

```
// Selecting the ShardRegion with name Counter
val counterRegion: ActorRef = ClusterSharding(system).shardRegion("Counter")
counterRegion ! Message
```